# Intersection with two columns in each matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, intersection

I would like to find the intersection of two columns in two matrix (see example below). So to find the position where A and B intersect -- in this case in position  3 and 5.

My solution so far, was to combine the two columns to one column and use `intersect` function on one column afterwards with a string. Is there a more elegant solution?

A = [1,1;1,3;1,4;2,1;2,5;3,1]

A =

```
 1     1
 1     3
 1     4
 2     1
 2     5
 3     1
```

B = [2,5;1,4]

B =

```
 2     5
 1     4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid combining the columns. When using intersect you can use the `rows` option.

```
A = [1,1;1,3;1,4;2,1;2,5;3,1]
B = [2,5;1,4]
[C,ia,ib] = intersect(B,A,'rows');

>>ib
     3
     5
```

Additionally, if you do not want the intersection result to be ordered you can use the `stable` option.

```
 [C,ia,ib] = intersect(B,A,'rows','stable');
 >>ib
     5
     3
```